# Should names be in good english?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

(This might be the wrong place to ask the question, please let me know).

Should I name my method `isStaticallyImported` or `isStaticlyImported`?
(They'd be pronounced pretty much the same way, I believe)

Comment: I think it's the wrong place to ask it too (opinion based) but: In my opinion code should be as well readable as possible. Your second version isn't. My two cents...

Comment: Using `isStaticlyImported` is just going to make you look bad to those who read your program.

Comment: Think this goes better in Programmers.SE

Comment: I agree that this should me moved elsewhere. However, my two cents, always spell in good English. If you had problem because it's too long, you surely find another way to shorten it. If you still have problem, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: poor identifiers waste time of readers - they have to think "what does it mean". And remember, programs are read many more times than written.

Answer (score 5):

Of course they should be in good english. Even if the human brain will likely have no problems reading garbled up words, compilers do not enjoy the same luxury.

How many times have you miswritten a variable name, then later on used the correct spelling, only to find out that the program crashed at run/compile time?

This problem is only amplified when working on code that was not written by you, because we think of things as, well, *things*, and having to specially remember that *the thing* had to be spelled in a special way is just an unneeded break to your workflow.

Comment: Right, so should it be the `isStaticallyImported` or `isStaticlyImported`? (The former looks correct, but the later looks more "natural" to dev eyes)

Comment: Not sure I understand the last part of your answer: the compiler doesn't care if the method is called `isStaticallyImported` or `sdfzsldjfhkj`...

Comment: @assylias I understand that. What I meant was, as a devs, would you prefer to see the former or the latter?

Comment: "the later looks more "naturally" to dev eyes" => No it doesn't. I'm a developer and it looks just plain ugly.

Comment: Yes, I have to deal with code written by others and I encounter this all the time. The misspelling I see most often is of *fulfillment*, misspelt as *fullfillment* and *fulfilment*. I have to use the misspelling because there's no way for me to change it to the correct spelling without making very very vast changes across project.

Comment: I voted to keep this question open -- you're not going to find a difference of opinion here. To spell my variables correctly or to not spell them correctly? You'd use the same judgement when writing an email.

Comment: @ADTC "fulfilment" is an acceptable (British) spelling, see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fulfilment.

Comment: To that point, shouldn't all fields/methods be named in AmericanEng just because the Americans invented most languages that we're using?

Comment: @ajb granted, I overlooked that. But the real issue goes beyond correct spelling, it also points to consistency. A group of American, British and Australian programmers can't work together if they insist on following their own version of English instead of standardizing on one (*which one?*). [**PS:** I should have probably mentioned _fullfilment_ also.]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your variables should be clear to the developer. You can name it whatever you want and it will work because the compiler doesn't care. When you name the variable in a human readable manner then developers after you will be able to read and understand your code much easier. You should name it "isStaticallyImported".

Answer (score 0):

They should be in the most easily understandable language for those using and maintaining it in my opinion.

I'm also pretty sure the compiler doesn't care about the quality of spelling.

Comment: The compiler cares about the spelling? Which compiler?

Comment: I missed the valuable word *doesnt*. I was referring to first answer which said compiler doesn't have the luxury of being able to understand garbled english

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit your answer according to your comment ;)